# What is my IP address in CIDR notation?

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I'm trying to following the [Quick Start Wordpress for Google App Engine](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/) guide; however, the Google Cloud Console appears to have changed slightly with respect to the instructions.

One of the instructions is to select **Assign IP Address**, and add [your  IP address](https://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=FmngV-frDM2DaIOMvfgP#q=whats%20my%20ip) to the list of **Authorized IP Addressed**. The link points to a Google search for "what's my IP address". However, the result does not look like it is in CIDR notation as required:

[image]

The IP address doesn't have a slash in it as in the CIDR example. Would it be OK just to enter the "public IP address" as it appears in Google search in the **Network** field?

**Update**
I tried entering my public IP address, but it appears with the gray italic text "Not saved" (see below), which does not look promising.

[image]

Comment: Is your public IP address statically allocated and guaranteed not to change, or are you using a consumer-grade broadband connection which probably has dynamically assigned addresses?  If you use a /32 suffix (meaning only that single address is authorized), you may get locked out if your cable modem reboots and you get assigned a different IP address from the range allocated to your ISP.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Just add '/32' to your ip... so it should be

```
82.217.236.160/32
```

Comment: Is this completely accurate ?  Every ip address can be converted to CIDR by just adding static `'/32' ` to it ?

Comment: Was there any answer to this?

Comment: yes it is. You can check via https://www.ripe.net/about-us/press-centre/IPv4CIDRChart_2015.pdf

Answer (score 8):

I used whois.geektools.com to look up the IP address you mentioned.  If that's
your actual IP address, then the IP range assigned to your ISP is:

```
inetnum: 82.217.192.0 - 82.217.255.255
netname: ZIGGO-CM
```

If you convert those IP addresses into binary, then the first 18 bits are
constant for that block of addresses, and the other 14 bits could vary, depending on how your ISP dishes them out to their customers.

So 82.217.192.0/18 (your ISP's block of IP addresses, in CIDR notation) might be a more convenient choice than the 82.217.236.160/32 value, corresponding to the single IP address currently assigned to you at the moment.

Comment: `whois.geektools.com` did not give me anything so I had to use a Python-based approach based on [this codereview post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/34093/200799) to confirm this (using this approach, I found the first 19 bits to be constant).